# How do I keep track of the iteration number while using each_char?

Tags: ruby, binary, decimal, iteration

I am learning Ruby and thought of making a Binary->Decimal converter. It gets a binary string and converts to decimal equivalent. Is there a way to keep track of the current iteration step in ruby so that the variable 'x' can be removed?

```
def convert(binary_string)
    decimal_equivalent = 0
    x=0   
    binary_string.reverse.each_char do |binary|
      decimal_equivalent += binary.to_i * (2 ** x)
    x+=1
    end

   return decimal_equivalent
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, by using the very powerful enumerator library:

```
require 'enumerator'
def convert(binary_string)
  decimal_equivalent = 0
  binary_string.reverse.enum_for(:each_char).each_with_index do |binary, i|
    decimal_equivalent += binary.to_i * (2 ** i)
  end
  return decimal_equivalent
end
```

Incidentally, you may be interested in `Array#pack`, and `String#unpack`. They have support for bit strings. Also, an even easier way to get this result is to use `#to_i`, e.g. `"101".to_i(2) #=> 5`

Answer (score 1):

```
binary_string.reverse.chars.each_with_index do |binary, i|
  decimal_equivalent += binary.to_i * (2 ** i)
end
```

Or on versions older than 1.8.7:

```
binary_string.reverse.split(//).each_with_index do |binary, i|
  decimal_equivalent += binary.to_i * (2 ** i)
end
```

Comment: it says undefined method 
chars for "0":String

Comment: What version of ruby are you using? "ruby --version" to find out

Comment: It looks like String#chars was added in 1.8.7. I'll update my answer with a version that works with earlier versions.

Comment: Ah. As Logan points out, using the enumerator library gives you enum_for(:each_char), which is the equivalent of the String#chars method introduced in 1.8.7.

Answer (score 0):

For the people (like me) who found this answer from google,

Here's the easy way to convert binary -> decimal in ruby (and back again):

```
# The String.to_i function can take an argument indicating
# the base of the number represented by the string.
decimal = '1011'.to_i(2)
# => 11

# Likewise, when converting a decimal number, 
# you can provide the base to the to_s function.
binary  = 25.to_s(2)
# => "11001"

# And you can pad the result using right-justify:
binary  = 25.to_s(2).rjust(8, '0')
# => "00011001"
```